# Should I refresh the ui data under a modal dialog

Tags: gui-design

I have a list view of students for a selected class 7a.

When I open the "Manage classes"-dialog and Delete class 7a should I do an instant refresh in the background or would it be better to do the action inside the dialog, close the dialog and then reload the whole state/page?

While this works well with deleting a class, closing dialog and refereshing the state, this does not work for the 2nd case:

A student(s) is selected and the "Manage subjects"-dialog is opened.
A subject checkbox is set and the attach button is pressed. The dialog is closed and the state/page is reloaded!

The ui state of the selected students is gone.

I guess I am atm too much into detail so I ask my question again:

What is the benefit of giving the user direct ui feedback by refreshing the data beneath the modal dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There usually isn't a need to refresh the data *beneath* a modal window while it is open. If real-time updates are needed (e.g. moving sliders to see a varying result), a different paradigm may be more useful.

However, changes should be reflected in the source list as soon as the modal window is closed.

> A student(s) is selected and the "Manage subjects"-dialog is opened. A
>   subject checkbox is set and the attach button is pressed. The dialog
>   is closed and the state/page is reloaded!
>
> The ui state of the selected students is gone.

That's the problem. The UI should update, but existing state (such as search/sort/selection) should be preserved.

Without delving into implementation details, I'd suggest merging the changes into the list instead of reloading the whole thing. If you must perform a full reload, then you need to consider restoring the state of the UI.

> What is the benefit of giving the user direct ui feedback by
>   refreshing the data beneath the modal dialog?

The user shouldn't have to wonder if the change happened (or worse, interact with stale data).

A quick scenario to illustrate these points. Let's say I need to update several students in a class.

1. I start by applying a filter.
2. I open each record and ensure that change ABC is made.
3. I close the modal dialog.
4. The associated item in the list updates, perhaps briefly changing color to indicate that it has changed (small, instant changes are easy to miss).
5. I can now easily see which item I need to edit next, rather than relying on memory to keep my place.

In this scenario, seeing the update is useful and losing state would be counterproductive. I should not have to reapply my filter(s) after every update and (possibly) scroll back to my previous location within the list.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. Ok then I have to keep a list for the schoolclasses and subjects on each dialog and when the dialog is closed I fire that data back and merge it with the list etc.. just tried and it works.

Comment: On the other side: " a different paradigm may be more useful..." What do you think of? Putting the schoolclasses/subjects dialog on the list view page without dialog? I had that before and the SE people told me thats too much UI at once ;-)

Comment: I think the dialog is a good paradigm for your situation. It lets the user focus on one task at a time which is my preference for this type of application unless a large number of changes are needed. If your users need to do a large number of changes at once, perhaps a "bulk management" screen could be useful.

Comment: Yes a large number of changes is of course done one time at the beginning of the school year/semester. After there are just minor changes.

Comment: btw. what is a "bulk management" screen in your opinion? A screen with everything on it?

Comment: By "bulk management", I mean a screen that allows a particular change to be applied to multiple items at once. For example, you might build a screen that allows managing the class assignments for a list of students without having to open and close each student. Since these screens can easily become overly complicated (usability and technically), I suggest keeping them to a single purpose rather than a single screen that lets you manage everything at once for multiple records.

Comment: Hm... not sure I understand you but in my case I do not have to open/close a student to assign the schoolclass. There is no such a thing atm to detach a pupil from a schoolclass as this can not happen. During a schoolyear if a pupil fails he must leave the class thus he is deleted from the class what is possible ;-)